# ARKit 3D Head tracking in scene

Tags: ios, scenekit, arkit

I am using ARKit to create an augmented camera app. When the ARSession initialises, a 3d character is shown in a ARSCNView. I am trying to get the character's 
head to track the ARCamera's point of view so they are always looking at the camera as the user moves to take a photo.

I've used Apple's chameleon demo, which adds a focus node that tracks the cameras point of view using SCNLookAtConstraint but I am getting 
strange behaviour. The head drops to the side and rotates as the ARCamera pans. If I add a SCNTransformConstraint to restrict the 
head movement to up/down/side-to-side, it stays vertical but then looks away and doesn't track.

I've tried picking the chameleon demo apart to see why mine is not working but after a few days I am stuck.

The code I am using is:

```
class Daisy: SCNScene, ARCharacter, CAAnimationDelegate {

    // Rig for animation
    private var contentRootNode: SCNNode! = SCNNode()
    private var geometryRoot: SCNNode!
    private var head: SCNNode!
    private var leftEye: SCNNode!
    private var rightEye: SCNNode!

    // Head tracking properties
    private var focusOfTheHead = SCNNode()
    private let focusNodeBasePosition = simd_float3(0, 0.1, 0.25)

    // State properties
    private var modelLoaded: Bool = false
    private var headIsMoving: Bool = false
    private var shouldTrackCamera: Bool = false



    /*
    * MARK: - Init methods
    */

    override init() {

        super.init()

        loadModel()
        setupSpecialNodes()
        setupConstraints()

    }


    /*
    * MARK: - Setup methods
    */

    func loadModel() {

        guard let virtualObjectScene = SCNScene(named: "daisy_3.dae", inDirectory: "art.scnassets") else {
            print("virtualObjectScene not intialised")
            return
        }

        let wrapper = SCNNode()

        for child in virtualObjectScene.rootNode.childNodes {
            wrapper.addChildNode(child)
        }

        self.rootNode.addChildNode(contentRootNode)

        contentRootNode.addChildNode(wrapper)

        hide()

        modelLoaded = true

    }


    private func setupSpecialNodes() {

        // Assign characters rig elements to nodes
        geometryRoot = self.rootNode.childNode(withName: "D_Rig", recursively: true)
        head = self.rootNode.childNode(withName: "D_RigFBXASC032Head", recursively: true)
        leftEye = self.rootNode.childNode(withName: "D_Eye_L", recursively: true)
        rightEye = self.rootNode.childNode(withName: "D_Eye_R", recursively: true)

        // Set up looking position nodes
        focusOfTheHead.simdPosition = focusNodeBasePosition

        geometryRoot.addChildNode(focusOfTheHead)

    }


    /* 
    * MARK: - Head animations
    */ 

    func updateForScene(_ scene: ARSCNView) {

        guard shouldTrackCamera, let pointOfView = scene.pointOfView else {
            print("Not going to updateForScene")
            return
        }

        followUserWithHead(to: pointOfView)

    }

    private func followUserWithHead(to pov: SCNNode) {

        guard !headIsMoving else { return }

        // Update the focus node to the point of views position
        let target = focusOfTheHead.simdConvertPosition(pov.simdWorldPosition, to: nil)

        // Slightly delay the head movement and the animate it to the new focus position
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2, execute: {
            let moveToTarget = SCNAction.move(to: SCNVector3(target.x, target.y, target.z), duration: 1.5)
            self.headIsMoving = true
            self.focusOfTheHead.runAction(moveToTarget, completionHandler: {
                self.headIsMoving = false
            })
        })

    }



    private func setupConstraints() {

        let headConstraint = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: focusOfTheHead)
        headConstraint.isGimbalLockEnabled = true

        let headRotationConstraint = SCNTransformConstraint(inWorldSpace: false) { (node, transform) -> SCNMatrix4 in

            // Only track the up/down and side to side movement
            var eulerX = node.presentation.eulerAngles.x
            var eulerZ = node.presentation.eulerAngles.z

            // Restrict the head movement so it doesn't rotate too far
            if eulerX < self.rad(-90) { eulerX = self.rad(-90) }
            if eulerX > self.rad(90) { eulerX = self.rad(90) }

            if eulerZ < self.rad(-30) { eulerZ = self.rad(-30) }
            if eulerZ > self.rad(30) { eulerZ = self.rad(30) }

            let tempNode = SCNNode()
            tempNode.transform = node.presentation.transform
            tempNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(eulerX, 0, eulerZ)
            return tempNode.transform

        }

        head?.constraints = [headConstraint, headRotationConstraint]

    }

    // Helper to convert degrees to radians
    private func rad(_ deg: Float) -> Float {
        return deg * Float.pi / 180
    }

}
```

The model in the Scene editor is:

[image]

Comment: [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnlookatconstraint). A node points in the direction of the negative z-axis of its local coordinate system. So the face of model should be facing -z axis

Comment: This was one of two issues I seen. The tracking was so off I wasn't sure if this was the problem originally. I'll answer the question fully to detail the other issues. Thanks Alok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem I was having. There were 2 issues:

1. The target in followUserWithHead should have converted the simdWorldPosition for it's parent and been convert from (not to)

   focusOfTheHead.parent!.simdConvertPosition(pov.simdWorldPosition, from: nil)
2. The local coordinates for the head node are incorrect. The z-axis should be the x-axis so when I got the focus the head movement tracking, the ear was always following the camera.

[image]

I didn't realise that the *Debug View Hierarchy* in Xcode will show the details of an SCNScene. This helped me to debug the scene and find where the nodes were tracking. You can export the scene as a dae and then load into SceneKit editor

**Edit:**
I used localFront as mnuages suggested in the comments below, which got the tracking working in the correct direction. The head did occasionally moved about though. I have put this down to the animation that was running on the model trying to apply a transform that was then changed on the next update cycle. I decided to remove the tracking from the head and use the same approach to track the eyes only.

Comment: the [`localFront`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnlookatconstraint/2867570-localfront) property of `SCNLookAtConstraint` might be useful if you want the +Y direction to be used instead of the -Z direction.

Comment: Thanks, how is the +Y direction set using localFront?